# how to remove all occurrences without removeAll method?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

suppose i want to write a method to remove a particular occurrence in a list. 
if the key is not on the list, return the list as it is.

methods that are given and i can use  : 
boolean isEmpty- true if and only if the list is empty
addFirst - adds a given object to the front of the list
removeFirst - removes an object from the front of the list
boolean isMem - checks if the given object is a member in the list
reverse - reverse the order of the items in the list

one of the codes i have found regarding the question is this code:

```
public void removeAllOccurrences(Object key){
List ans = new List();
while (!isEmpty()){
    Object data = removeFirst();
     if (!data.equals(key)){
        ans.addFirst(data);
    }
}
while(!ans.isEmpty()){
addFirst(ans.removeFirst());
```

but i didn't get the last part : while the list is not empty, add an item in front of the list, and then remove it.. ?

also, i would suggest the following code, will gladly hear your professional opinion:

```
List ans = new list(); 
 if (!(isMember(key) )
   return new list();
else
    while (!ans.isEmpty ) {
        Link first = curr.link;
        if (!(data.equals(key))
             ans.addFirst(data) ; 
           curr=curr.next; 
          }
```

Comment: Take a look at the [removeIf-Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) introduced in Java 8. `list.removeIf(obj -> !obj.equals(otherObject))`.

Comment: In the code you suggest, if the element is not a member you are not returning the current list but a new, empty list; as for the while in that code, see Farrandu's answer

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question: the `while` block has emptied this list, and the `ans` object contains the new list, so, at the end, the method drains the `ans` contents to `this` list.

Regarding the second code block, the `while` block will never execute because the `ans` object has just been created, so `ans.isEmpty()` will always return `true`.

Comment: ans can have elements added in the while loop, so the second while block can be executed EDIT sorry, just realize you were talking about the code Invader suggested

Comment: I don't get it: isn't the second code block a full implementation for the `removeAllOccurrences` method?

Comment: could you suggest how can i improve my piece of code?

Comment: @Farrandu Yes; I think the first code block is one Invader found as an implementation and the second one is Invader's implementation of the same functionality

Comment: @Invader (1) When you do if(!isMember(key)) return new list(); you want to return this object or a copy: if (!isMember(key)) return this; (2) as Farrandu said, in while (!ans.isEmpty), ans haven't been modified so it's empty and then nothing's done. In the body of that while I don't even know what are you trying to do: the first variable is not used, data is not declared, and curr should have to advance until somewhere, but where?

Comment: curr should advance until the next one is empty, i.e it went from the first item in the list until the end.. now i understood better my mistakes. tnx